# Shouldn't it be “…garbage is dumped” instead of “are’?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, uncountable-nouns, countability

Garbage is singular and I don't think quantity has something to do here.

> Woman: Talk dirty to me!
>   Man: 14 billion pounds of garbage are dumped into the ocean every year. Most of it is plastic.

[image]

Comment: The subject is 14 billion pounds ... which is plural

Answer (score 1):

Both "is" and "are" would be possible her depending on whether you treat this as a plural (5 billion pounds), or singular (considering the "pounds" to be a unit and function more like an adjective describing a singular "garbage".

You will see both interpretations in use, often determined by what comes after the verb.

However if you have a counting word that isn't a unit you must use a plural.

> five pounds of flour (are/is)...
>
> five pieces of cake are...

Comment: Yes I'd always use are with pieces but I never treat unit as a plural. It's more like a regional thing. No?

Comment: The image macro in the question suggests that "5 million pounds of garbage are" is an idiomatic usage in the USA.